# Laravel 5.5 saving multiple photos with 1 file input

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a form with 1 file input and my goal is to store all picture that I select with CTRL+click.

The response of my ajax call always returns only 1 filename how can I make it return an object of all my files?

My input field:

```
<?php echo Form::file('photos[]', ['multiple', 'id' => 'photos']); ?>
```

My Ajax call:

```
let token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
let photos = $('input[type=file]').val().split('\\').pop();

var values = {
    photos: photos,
}

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/upload',
   dataType: 'JSON',
   data: {
       "_method": 'POST',
       "_token": token,
       "values": values
   },
   success:function(data){
       console.log('success');
       console.log(data);
   },
   error:function(){
   },
});
```

My controller method:

```
/**
 * Handles the upload of the images.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function uploadSubmit(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')){  

        $values = $request->values;

        return response()->json([
                                    'response'  => 'This is post method',
                                    'values'    => $values
                                ]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://www.code-hound.com/upload-multiple-files-at-once-with-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code and make few changes in ajax code. Add below parameters in your code.

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

And add `var formData = new FormData($("#formID")[0]);` line before AJAX starts.

Or Check below code and make changes according to you code.

You should use below jquery code to upload filed using AJAX.

```
var formData = new FormData($(form)[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: form.action,
    type: form.method,
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content"));
    },
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```

Controller Side Code :

```
foreach($request->only('files') as $files){
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if(is_file($file)) {    // not sure this is needed
            $fname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $string = str_random(16);
            $ext = $file->guessExtension();
            $file_name = $string . '.' .  $ext;
            $filepath = 'uploads/' . $file_name;
            $file->storeAs('uploads/', $file_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it seems to be better working  but I get no info(filename etc.) of the images I upload

Comment: You have any idea how I can get the data of the files?

Comment: It's a lot clearer now, just a little question: where is the 'docs' folder located? Do I need to make it myself or will this be auto generated?

Comment: Edited answer or you can read this laravel documentation you will get idea about storing files. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#storing-uploaded-files